# Ajax call to external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to access on or two data attributes from my personal Duolingo account. When punching in the following URL a JSON object is returned:
http://www.duolingo.com/users/username (I've replaced my id with "username" in the url).

```
var getDuolingoData = function() {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://www.duolingo.com/users/daniel692007&callback=?",
        dataType: "json"
    });

}

getDuolingoData().then(function(json) {

    console.log(json.site_streak); // this log is causing the error

});
```

When I try and log a key from the returned object, however, the following error is logged to the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Ajax is fairly new to me, Duolingo don't have an API that I know of and as this is an external URL I believe the `dataType` must be set to `jsonp` due to CORS.

Is there an obvious reason that I am not able to access the JSON object I can see when visiting the specified URL?

TY

Comment: Can you show us the portion of the code causing the error?

Comment: Please add more of the code, including where the key is logged.

Comment: go to network tab in the browser developer tools and take a screenshot of the returned response

Comment: Have added now.

Comment: Try a `console.log(json)` inside your `then()`

Comment: It may be that the url your are calling is returning HTML instead of JSON. The < character may belong to the opening <HTML> tag. if you remove dataType: json and log the response what do you see.

Comment: I just looked at the response in dev tools as suggested by @PeterWilson, it seems I am pulling in HTML and not the JSON that is loaded when visiting the URL I've specified. Is there a way around this since the page is just displaying a JSON object when you visit the URL?

Comment: Does this site even support JSONP or CORS? Where is it documented that your URL is correct? BTW in your code you've specified json not jsonp, but I tested adding it and it makes no difference to the response

Comment: Unsure, as I mentioned, Ajax is new to me. From what I know, Duolingo doesn't have an API. Perhaps what I am wanting to do isn't possible. All I know is, I ping the URL provided, a JSON object is returned to the browser and I would like to access some of the keys in that object.

Comment: Yes but due to CORS restrictions you can't do that via AJAX. And JSONP is unlikely to work unless the site supports it, either. According to this https://www.duolingo.com/comment/16214728/Duolingo-API there is no official API, so you can't ever expect this to work. _However_, a server-side HTTP request to the same URL should work - i.e. not executed from a browser, and therefore not subject to CORS restrictions. So you could write it in C#, PHP, Python, whatever script you use on the server, and then output the results to your own page.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to do what I am trying to do? If so, I'm not wedded to using Ajax. Is there another way that I can access keys inside the object that is displayed when the URL is pinged?

Comment: See my edit to the above comment. Zetawars' answer is also on the right track, although obviously C# may not be your language of choice. P.S. Remember to remove the "callback" parameter from the request and just request directly http://www.duolingo.com/users/daniel692007 when you do this in your code

Comment: Okay. Interesting. Thank you for letting me know. Cheers.

Comment: If you want to learn more you should google CORS and find out what it is and why it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue happened to me. I was unable to solve it using jsonp. What i ended up doing was to make an action in the controller that recieved the json from external url and send it to the ajax call.

For exmaple

```
return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/ActionInProject/ProjectController",
    });
```

then in the Controller it will be different for whichever server side language is being used. For me it was C# so i did something like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ActionInProject()
{
   using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var response = client.GetAsync("someothersite.com/api/link");
      return Json(client.GetAsync());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request with Postman 
and I found it not valid json in the respone you can find below what is returned of the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html dir="ltr"><head><title>Duolingo</title><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta name="robots" content="NOODP"><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/nojs/splash"></noscript><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Duolingo"><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=570060128"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="nWyTCDRw4VJS_b6YSRZiFmmj56EawZpZMhHtKXt7lkU"><link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aiahmijlpehemcpleichkcokhegllfjl"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/images/duolingo-touch-icon.png"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/favicon.ico"><link href="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/css/ltr-9f45956e.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link rel="manifest" href="/gcm/manifest.json"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script>window.duo={"detUiLanguages":["en","es","pt","it","fr","de","ja","zs","zt","ko","ru","hi","hu","tr"],"troubleshootingForumId":647,"uiLanguage":"en","unsupportedDirections":[],"oldWebUrlWhitelist":["^/activity_stream$","^/admin_tools$","^/c/$","^/certification/","^/comment/","^/course/","^/course_announcement/","^/courses$","^/courses/","^/debug/","^/dictionary/","^/discussion$","^/event/","^/forgot_password$","^/guidelines$","^/help$","^/j$","^/mobile$","^/p/$","^/pm/","^/power_practice/","^/preview/.+/","^/quit_classroom_session","^/redirect/","^/referred","^/register_user$","^/reset_password","^/settings/reset_lang","^/skill_practice/","^/team/","^/teams$","^/topic/","^/translation/","^/translations$","^/translations/","^/troubleshooting$","^/ui_strings/","^/upload$","^/vocab","^/welcome$","^/welcome/","^/word","^/words$"]}</script><script>window.duo.version="c89bfb9"</script><script>!function(r){function n(t){if(e[t])return e[t].exports;var s=e[t]={i:t,l:!1,exports:{}};return r[t].call(s.exports,s,s.exports,n),s.l=!0,s.exports}var t=window.webpackJsonp;window.webpackJsonp=function(e,i,o){for(var c,a,f,d=0,u=[];d<e.length;d++)a=e[d],s[a]&&u.push(s[a][0]),s[a]=0;for(c in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,c)&&(r[c]=i[c]);for(t&&t(e,i,o);u.length;)u.shift()();if(o)for(d=0;d<o.length;d++)f=n(n.s=o[d]);return f};var e={},s={31:0};n.e=function(r){function t(){c.onerror=c.onload=null,clearTimeout(a);var n=s[r];0!==n&&(n&&n[1](new Error("Loading chunk "+r+" failed.")),s[r]=void 0)}var e=s[r];if(0===e)return new Promise(function(r){r()});if(e)return e[2];var i=new Promise(function(n,t){e=s[r]=[n,t]});e[2]=i;var o=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript",c.charset="utf-8",c.async=!0,c.timeout=12e4,n.nc&&c.setAttribute("nonce",n.nc),c.src=n.p+""+({0:"js/vendor",1:"js/app",2:"strings/zh-TW",3:"strings/zh-CN",4:"strings/vi",5:"strings/uk",6:"strings/tr",7:"strings/tl",8:"strings/th",9:"strings/te",10:"strings/ta",11:"strings/ru",12:"strings/ro",13:"strings/pt",14:"strings/pl",15:"strings/pa",16:"strings/nl-NL",17:"strings/ko",18:"strings/ja",19:"strings/it",20:"strings/id",21:"strings/hu",22:"strings/hi",23:"strings/fr",24:"strings/es",25:"strings/en",26:"strings/el",27:"strings/de",28:"strings/cs",29:"strings/bn",30:"strings/ar"}[r]||r)+"-"+{0:"2b9feda7",1:"662ee5e7",2:"c444b0a9",3:"a5658bf8",4:"3ea447d8",5:"1573893a",6:"c32ed883",7:"52cac8bc",8:"2c58adbb",9:"681aaba6",10:"d05b78c6",11:"f4071afb",12:"a1349f5c",13:"6a57ec9f",14:"762dfc94",15:"8a02897a",16:"4e429b1e",17:"8e921ddf",18:"524cc86b",19:"8df42324",20:"7d8a8fc5",21:"4fde5d79",22:"509b8809",23:"9f09bcfb",24:"77da48d4",25:"44cfb321",26:"13b268cc",27:"c0cac402",28:"3ecdeec1",29:"dfd2b224",30:"074ffddd"}[r]+".js";var a=setTimeout(t,12e4);return c.onerror=c.onload=t,o.appendChild(c),i},n.m=r,n.c=e,n.d=function(r,t,e){n.o(r,t)||Object.defineProperty(r,t,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},n.n=function(r){var t=r&&r.__esModule?function(){return r.default}:function(){return r};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(r,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,n)},n.p="/",n.oe=function(r){throw console.error(r),r}}([])</script><script src="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/js/vendor-2b9feda7.js"></script>                       <script src="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/strings/en-44cfb321.js"></script>     <script src="//d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/js/app-662ee5e7.js"></script></body></html>
```

as you can see the JSON is wrapped inside a HTML page which is not valid JSON syntax it something related to the API itself. it returns a page instead of JSON object .

Comment: So I'm sure I'll be exposing my ignorance here, but this essentially means I cannot access that beautiful, buzzy, JSON object that is returned every time I ping the URL directly? Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: do you have any access to this API?

Comment: Nope. It's just an external URL.

Comment: Visiting http://www.duolingo.com/users/daniel692007 (without the spurious callback parameter) works fine in Postman and returns JSON. I suspect the response seen above (which looks like the HTML for the homepage of the site) is because the server is unsure what to do with the request, or thinks it's potentially malicious.